# How can I intercept elements in an IQueryable regardless of how many transforms are applied?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to wrap an `IQueryable<T>` so that when the result is finally iterated I will have access to each element as it is returned.

To achieve this, I tried creating a `QueryableWrapper<T>` class which acts as a man-in-the-middle for the real queryable instance.

Then, when my repository is asked for its `IQueryable<T>` I returned this wrapper instead. This works fine until the consumer applies any further LINQ statements such as `Where` etc.

What I need to do is have my Repository intercept every item returned from the query as the consumer iterates it. This is so I can do the following

1. Is the result a domain object?
2. If so, then keep track of the object in case it is modified

I managed to get a bit further by also wrapping the result of `Provider` - but this crashes when the consumer does an `OrderBy`, because my result is not an `IOrderedEnumerable`.

I could implement this, but then I fear I am going down a rabbit hole, and there should be an easier way to achieve this.

```
    internal class QueryableWrapper<T> : IQueryable<T>
    {
        private readonly IQueryable<T> Source;
        private readonly IQueryProvider QueryProvider;

        public QueryableWrapper(IQueryable<T> source)
        {
            CollectionName = collectionName;
            DbContext = dbContext;
            Source = source;
            QueryProvider = new QueryProviderWrapper<T>(source.Provider);
        }

        public Type ElementType => Source.ElementType;

        public Expression Expression => Source.Expression;

        public IQueryProvider Provider => QueryProvider;

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() =>
            new EnumeratorWrapper<T>(Source.GetEnumerator());

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }


    internal class EnumeratorWrapper<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> Source;

        public EnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerator<T> source)
        {
            Source = source;
        }

        public T Current => Source.Current;

        object? IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Source.Dispose();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            bool result = Source.MoveNext();
            if (result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Intercepted " + Source.Current.GetType().FullName);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Source.Reset();
        }
    }

    internal class QueryProviderWrapper<T> : IQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly IQueryProvider Source;

        public QueryProviderWrapper(IQueryProvider source)
        {
            Source = source;
        }

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression) => CreateQuery<T>(expression);

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
            IQueryable<TElement> result = Source.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression);
            return new QueryableWrapper<TElement>(source: result);
        }

        public object? Execute(Expression expression) => Execute<T>(expression);

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) => Source.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }
}
```

```cs
internal class QueryableWrapper<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly IQueryable<T> Source;

    public QueryableWrapper(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }

    public Type ElementType => Source.ElementType;

    public Expression Expression => Source.Expression;

    public IQueryProvider Provider => Source.Provider;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() =>
        new EnumeratorWrapper<T>(Source.GetEnumerator());

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}


internal class EnumeratorWrapper<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> Source;

    public EnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerator<T> source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }

    public T Current => Source.Current;

    object? IEnumerator.Current => Source.Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Source.Dispose();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        bool result = Source.MoveNext();
        if (result)
            Console.WriteLine("Intercepted!");
        return result;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Source.Reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simply because orderBy in `queryable.OrderBy` will return a new `IQueryable` that is not wrapped. The new `MoveNext` is from the new instance provided by the new function.

In your foreach, the one used is the unwrapped.

Try this:

```
var data = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
var queryable = new QueryableWrapper<string>(data.AsQueryable().OrderBy(x => x));
foreach (string datum in queryable)
    Console.WriteLine("Ordered datum = " + datum);
```

Create the full queryable expression and then create the wrapper around the final result to have it intercept it.

The documentation explains it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution

> After a LINQ query is created by a user, it is converted to a command tree. A command tree is a representation of a query that is compatible with the Entity Framework. The command tree is then executed against the data source
>
> At what point query expressions are executed can vary. LINQ queries are always executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when the query variable is created. This is called deferred execution. You can also force a query to execute immediately, which is useful for caching query results. This is described later in this topic.

Comment: I think the logical follow-up question is then: how does an OrderBy enumerate its source? Which properties does it access that bypass GetEnumerator?

Comment: It doesn't. It uses the source to create the query expression and only when the enumeration is needed (like foreach or tolist) does the last iquerable enumerate the result of the full query.

Comment: _"It uses the source"_ - but that isn't exposed through the IQueryable. My point was that your should explain that in your answer. :) Yes, the enumerator is only called when you enumerate the queryable, which happens on the last queryable in the chain. Note that Linq to Objects is not Linq to Entities. And yes, OrderBy _does_ return an IQuerable that is wrapped, namely an IOrderedQueryable.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the title of my question because it is really the last line I of the question I was interested in. Do you know how that can be done?

Comment: You can't. It's not transformations, it's filtering, transformations and much more. Imagine that you add two where clauses the one after the other. The first  filters the collection to 1 million rows the second to 100. Only the 100 will ever enter memory and be iterated.

Comment: I need to hook into the process so that at the very end I get to return the enumerator, so I can inspect each value iterated

Comment: Then try my example. Wrap only the last iquerable and you'll inspect all the values returned by the query.

Comment: I _guess_ that @PeterMorris wants to return an IQueryable from some kind of repository, on which the caller can call Linq methods or any IQueryable extension method, and that they can't ensure that their method is called last. But then that information should be in the question.

Comment: IOrderedEnumerable<T> is just a marker class, tagging my class with that made it work.

Answer (score 2):

`IOrderedEnumerable<T>` is just a tag class. I was able to tag my `IQueryableWrapper<T>` with that interface without implementing any code and everything worked!

The final code is as follows:

```
public class MyRepository<TWhatever>
{
    public IQueryable<TWhatever> Query() =>
        new QueryableWrapper<TWhatever>(TheRealOne);
}
```

```
namespace DomainDrivenDesign.MongoDB.Persistence
{
    internal class QueryableWrapper<T> : IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
    {
        private readonly IQueryable<T> Source;
        private readonly Lazy<IQueryProvider> QueryProvider;

        public QueryableWrapper(IQueryable<T> source)
        {
            Source = source;
            QueryProvider = new Lazy<IQueryProvider>(() =>
                new QueryProviderWrapper<T>(collectionName, dbContext, source.Provider));
        }

        public Type ElementType => Source.ElementType;

        public Expression Expression => Source.Expression;

        public IQueryProvider Provider => QueryProvider.Value;

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => new EnumeratorWrapper<T>(Source.GetEnumerator());

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }


    internal class EnumeratorWrapper<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> Source;

        public EnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerator<T> source)
        {
            CollectionName = collectionName;
            DbContext = dbContext;
            Source = source;
        }

        public T Current => Source.Current;

        object? IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Source.Dispose();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            bool result = Source.MoveNext();
            if (result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Intercepted!");
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Source.Reset();
        }
    }

    internal class QueryProviderWrapper<T> : IQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly IQueryProvider Source;

        public QueryProviderWrapper(IQueryProvider source)
        {
            Source = source;
        }

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression) => CreateQuery<T>(expression);

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
            IQueryable<TElement> result = Source.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression);
            return new QueryableWrapper<TElement>(result);
        }

        public object? Execute(Expression expression) => Execute<T>(expression);

        // Note that this bypasses Enumerator if the query ends with a scalar
        // such as .First()
        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) => Source.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }
}
```